# question in least angle regression paper [Efron et al. (2004)]

Tags: lars

I am reading [Efron et al. (2004), *Ann. Statist.*, **32**, 2, "Least angle regression"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1083178935). I have struggled with formula 5.19 for some days. It says the minimizing resolution of lasso occurs strictly inside the simplex 5.19. But I can't understand the reason. In order to express more clearly, I paste the related text in this paper.

[image: pic1]
   [image: pic2]

I can't understand how lasso problem (1.5) equals (5.18)-(5.19).

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It's better to type out quotations -  the text is then searchable, & accessible to visually impaired users with screen readers. You can use LaTeX mark-up for equations.